# How to Select/ Get Razor Html Helper Tag By Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Here it is my razor code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.CategoryLookUp, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and here I can Select element by Id:

```
$("#CategoryId").val() //etc.
```

but I want to select all `Html.DropDownListFor` or any kind of helper to add a CSS class.

I just simply add a new `{ @class = "form-control myClass" })` and it works fine, but over 1000+ dropdownList are in my project, for that I wrote a class, and now I want to add this class to all dropdownList.

Comment: why not make a CSS change using select tag and the class name both as qualifiers and put styling of myClass in that? Since you do not want to go through the hassle of find repalce all i think that can be a time savor?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) use some tricks to find and replace with visual studio tools, for example: 
find `"form-control` and replace it with `"form-control myClass"`.

2) If you want to set one or some style for all controls in your project you can put the style in a global stylesheet file like this:

```
select {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

You can use this jQuery selector to find all of your dropdowns:

```
var allDropdowns = $("select.form-control");
```

or

```
var allDropdowns = $("select.myClass");
```

or even:

```
var allDropdowns = $("select");
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your information. but I already added class to all dropdown and dropdown list, that's I don't want actually. I want to get html helper, and change some behavior. but I can't.